# Running calculations on multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: php, loops

This is probably a real simple question but I'm looking for the most memory efficient way of finding out data on a particular multi-dimensional array.

An example of the array:

```
[0] => Array(
    [fin] => 2
    [calc] => 23.34
    [pos] => 6665
)
[1] => Array(
    [fin] => 1
    [calc] => 25.14
    [pos] => 4543
)
[2] => Array(
    [fin] => 7
    [calc] => 21.45
    [pos] => 4665
)
```

I need a method of identifying the values of the following things:

- The max 'calc'
- The min 'calc'
- The max 'pos'
- The min 'pos'
- (you get the gist)

The only way I can think of is manually looping through each value and adjusting an integer so for example:

```
function find_lowest_calc($arr) {
    $int = null;
    foreach($arr['calc'] as $value) {
        if($int == null || $int > $value) {
            $int = $value;
        }
    }
    return $int;
}
```

The obvious drawbacks of a method like this is I would have to create a new function for each value in the array (or at least implement a paramater to change the array key) and it will slow up the app by looping through the whole array 3 or more times just to get the values. The original array could have over a hundred values.

I would assume that there would be an internal function to gather all of (for example) the 'calc' values into a temporary single array so I could use the max function on it.

Any ideas?

Dan

Comment: Code in assembly! that'd be very memory efficient.

Comment: Ignore previous comment. Cannot say about memory efficiency, but you can generalize your function, something like this `find($arr, $bool_min_or_max, $key)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you receiving the array?  If it is your code which is creating the array, you could calculate the minimum and maximum values as you are reading in the data values:

```
$minCalc = null;
$arr = array();
for(...){

  //read in 'calc' value
  $subArr = array();
  $subArr['calc'] = //...
  if ($minCalc === null || $minCalc > $subArr['calc']){
    $minCalc = $subArr['calc'];
  }

  //read in other values
  //...

  $arr[] = $subArr;
}
```

Also, in your `find_lowest_calc` function, you should use the triple equals operator (`===`) to determine whether the `$int` variable is null.  This is because the statement `$int == null` will also return true if `$int` equals `0`, because `null` equals `0` when converted to an integer.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in accepting. I never thought of doing this. The array is compiled within the system so I could easily perform the calculations alongside in the same loop. Good shout! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$input = array(
    array(
        'fin'  => 2
        'calc' => 23.34
        'pos'  => 6665
    ),
    array(
        'fin'  => 1
        'calc' => 25.14
        'pos'  => 4543
    ),
    array(
        'fin'  => 7
        'calc' => 21.45
        'pos'  => 4665
    )
);

$output = array(
    'fin'  => array(),
    'calc' => array(),
    'pos'  => array(),
);
foreach ( $input as $data ) {
    $output['fin'][]  = $data['fin'];
    $output['calc'][] = $data['calc'];
    $output['pos'][]  = $data['pos'];
}

max($output['fin']); // max fin
max($output['calc']); // max calc
min($output['fin']); // min fin
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to speed that up, besides calculating all three values at once. The reason for this is that you always need to loop through the array to find the sub-arrays. Even if you find a bultin function, the time complexity will be the same. The only way to make a real difference is by using another datastructure (i.e, not any of the bultin ones, but one you write yourself).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to crate a new function for each value, just pass the key you want in the function

```
function find_lowest($arr, $indexkey) {
    $int = null;
    foreach($arr[$indexkey] as $value) {
        if($int == null || $int > $value) {
            $int = $value;
        }
    }
    return $int;
}
```

As php is not type-safe, you should be fine passing both string or int index